# Scraping, Curl: cookie extracted does not work, broser's does

Tags: curl, cookies, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the site www.lider.cl using ruby and Nokogiri

In particular i'm interested in the product list. The list for a category is for example:

```
URL1 = https://www.lider.cl/walmart/catalog/category.jsp?id=cat320019&pId=CF_Nivel1_000003&navAction=jump&navCount=0
```

Upon inspecting network section on browser, I detected that in order to get the list of products programmatically without having to use a javascript-able browser library, I could POST directly to:

```
URL2 = https://www.lider.cl/walmart/category/product/food/foodProductListContent.jsp?catName=Arroz"%"20y"%"20Legumbres&pId=CF_Nivel1_000003&cId=&sId=cat320019
```

Now, in order to execute URL2 correctly, I need to pass a cookie.

So my approach is to call URL1 first, get the cookie and pass it to URL2 like this:

```
curl "https://www.lider.cl/walmart/category/product/food/foodProductListContent.jsp?catName=Arroz"%"20y"%"20Legumbres&pId=CF_Nivel1_000003&cId=&sId=cat320019" -H "Cookie: JSESSIONID=55580F4B138C8660989405EFF8665988.CL2NTS1P60082_store16;"
```

If I get JSESSIONID by inspecting firefox and execute the above command, the resulting page in curl is correct. However if I curl URL1 and get the cookie to pass it to URL2, it does not work, I get a page saying the search was invalid.

Can anyone help me understand how firefox gets a valid cookie but nt curl?

Regards

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". There's nothing in your question that shows it's related to Ruby or Nokogiri except your statement saying you're using Ruby and Nokogiri. Please don't tag a question without code showing their use. This appears to only be a curl question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `--cookie-jar` and `--cookie`.

```
$ curl --cookie-jar /tmp/myCookies "$URL1"
$ curl --cookie /tmp/myCookies "$URL2"
```